# Extracting Output From Bespoke Function With A For Loop in R

Tags: r

I've seen a few questions out there dealing with similar issues but nothing quite the same when working on a bespoke function that contains a for loop. Below is some dummy code that prints output I want to use further. Ideally, I would assign this to a new variable. Is it possible to take numeric output and store it somehow?

```
my_vector <- as.numeric(1:100 * 100)

progressive <- function(pretax_revenue, tax_rate = 0.05) {
  for (i in 1:length(pretax_revenue)) {
    taxable_revenue <- (pretax_revenue * tax_rate)
    tax_rate <- tax_rate + 0.005
    print(taxable_revenue[i])
  }
}

progressive(my_vector)
```

Edit: thanks so those who have replied so far. I either (quite possibly) not advanced enough in R to fully comprehend the answers or I may have equally not been clear enough in my initial effort.

The output I get from the code above is:

```
[1] 5
[1] 11
[1] 18
[1] 26
[1] 35
[1] 45
[1] 56
[1] 68
[1] 81
[1] 95
[1] 110
```

and so on... every observation in my_vector is multiplied by an incremental decimal figure and I'm not sure that has translated into some of the answers put forward. I apologise in advance for not being clear enough.

Comment: Are you looking to store the output in a vector?

Comment: Hello there! Yes, I am trying to store the output as a new vector from which I can then further manipulate i.e. cumsum(new_vector)... Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first assignment in the loop body is not indexed on the LHS. And the RHS instance of pretax_revenue is not indexed either.  And you don’t pre-dimension it. Both of such errors seem to be common failure modes for programming newcomers. After exiting the loop you should use ‘return()’ to send the complete object back to the calling environment.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your comment. Can you just clarify what exactly 'it' is that I haven't pre-dimensioned? Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

You can create `taxable_revenue` an empty vector of double type with the same length as `pretax_revenue`. Then, assign the results to `taxable_revenue` by the index number within for loop. After that, return the finalised vector.

```
progressive <- function(pretax_revenue, tax_rate = 0.05) {
  taxable_revenue <- vector("double", length(pretax_revenue))
  for (i in seq_along(pretax_revenue)) {
    taxable_revenue[i] <- pretax_revenue[i] * tax_rate
    tax_rate <- tax_rate + 0.005
  }
  return(taxable_revenue)
}

x <- progressive(my_vector)
head(x)
# [1]  5 11 18 26 35 45

class(x)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is increase the multiple by 0.005 starting at 0.05 (I've now published my output above in the original question). What is in your approach that is leading to a different output?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the logic of your function. I have updated my answer accordingly. In your question, `pretax_revenue * tax_rate` within for loop do the calculation on the entire vector but you only need the result based on the for loop step. It's more efficient to use `pretax_revenue[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list to store the results and return it once the function finishes. Keep in mind that `taxable_revenue <- pretax_revenue * tax_rate` is a vectorized multiplication.

```r
my_vector <- as.numeric(1:100 * 100)

progressive <- function(pretax_revenue, tax_rate = 0.05) {
  
  results <- vector('list', length(pretax_revenue))
  for (i in 1:length(pretax_revenue)) {
    taxable_revenue <- pretax_revenue * tax_rate #this is a vectorized operation
    tax_rate <- tax_rate + 0.005
    results[[i]] <- taxable_revenue
  }
  return(results)
}

progressive_result <- progressive(my_vector)

head(progressive_result, 2)
#> [[1]]
#>   [1]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90
#>  [19]  95 100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175 180
#>  [37] 185 190 195 200 205 210 215 220 225 230 235 240 245 250 255 260 265 270
#>  [55] 275 280 285 290 295 300 305 310 315 320 325 330 335 340 345 350 355 360
#>  [73] 365 370 375 380 385 390 395 400 405 410 415 420 425 430 435 440 445 450
#>  [91] 455 460 465 470 475 480 485 490 495 500
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   [1]   5.5  11.0  16.5  22.0  27.5  33.0  38.5  44.0  49.5  55.0  60.5  66.0
#>  [13]  71.5  77.0  82.5  88.0  93.5  99.0 104.5 110.0 115.5 121.0 126.5 132.0
#>  [25] 137.5 143.0 148.5 154.0 159.5 165.0 170.5 176.0 181.5 187.0 192.5 198.0
#>  [37] 203.5 209.0 214.5 220.0 225.5 231.0 236.5 242.0 247.5 253.0 258.5 264.0
#>  [49] 269.5 275.0 280.5 286.0 291.5 297.0 302.5 308.0 313.5 319.0 324.5 330.0
#>  [61] 335.5 341.0 346.5 352.0 357.5 363.0 368.5 374.0 379.5 385.0 390.5 396.0
#>  [73] 401.5 407.0 412.5 418.0 423.5 429.0 434.5 440.0 445.5 451.0 456.5 462.0
#>  [85] 467.5 473.0 478.5 484.0 489.5 495.0 500.5 506.0 511.5 517.0 522.5 528.0
#>  [97] 533.5 539.0 544.5 550.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>